# bootstrap modal conflicts with mixitup filterable portfolio

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, mixitup

I have problems with my filterable portfolio.

The Mixitup filterable portfolio is working fine, but when I add a link to a bootstrap modal and test it all my images in my portfolio shrinks to zero and gets the modal background. But nothing shows.

Whats wrong?

**Here is a link to the folder :** 
http://lmcdesign.dk/filterable_portfolio.zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also working on a personal project where i used Mixit filter and inside it tried to open Bootstrap modal. I got the same hidden elements issue 
I found the solution on official git.

Bootstrap uses the attribute data-toggle internally, which interferes with MixItUp.

Use the selectors.control configuration option to specify an additional selector by which to restrict MixItUp controls. This can be a class name or attribute etc.

```
mixitup(container, {
selectors: {
    control: '[data-mixitup-control]'
}
```

}

```
<button type="button" data-mixitup-control data-filter=".red">Red</button>
```

Blue
Sort Desc

https://github.com/patrickkunka/mixitup/issues/268